# How to edit (modify) default search texts in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I am making a web site in my own language. (My language is Turkmen. No language pack for my language exists in joomla.)

I cannot edit default search texts. For example in joomla there are 
"Search Keyword:", "Ordering:", "Total: 0 results found." strings.
I cannot change these to my own language.

I have:

- Searched language folder and looked search.ini files,
- Searched in db, if my language pack exists.

What can I do?

Comment: If you can't find your language pack - i'd recommend sending a feature request to add your language. or add your own language, then submit it to joomla to be reviewed and added

Answer (score 2):

When translating joomla core language there is a whole set of files to translate, in the site language as well as the admin language folders.

To translate the specific terms you would need to look at the en-GB.com_search.ini and translate to your correspondent tk-TM.com_search ini, in the site language folder.

I noticed that a Turkmen language pack (alpha) has been added to joomlacode the recent week. Perhaps this is useful for you, and you might even be able to help them make it stable and complete. See it here: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/turkmen_joomla/frs/
* Not sure the naming convention of the package/files are correct when using tm-TM for language-COUNTRY for that project. I think it would be tk-TM

Comment: I looked in search.ini file. I could not find that words to translate.

Comment: Look in /language/en-GB/en-gb.com_search.ini
there you should see the strings like these:
COM_SEARCH_ORDERING="Ordering:"
COM_SEARCH_SEARCH="Search"
COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_AGAIN="Search Again"
COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_KEYWORD="Search Keyword:"
COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_KEYWORD_N_RESULTS_1="<strong>Total: One result found.</strong>"
COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_KEYWORD_N_RESULTS="<strong>Total: %s results found.</strong>"

Comment: I changed letters into latin alphabet, and saved in UTF-8 format. In spite, joomla does not show that letters, it shows symbols only. How come?

Comment: When symbols are shown it does indicate that the file has wrong encoding still. Try open it using an editor like Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ and make sure it is saved with format UTF-8 (No BOM)